# CURL возвращает bool(false). Почему?

Tags: php, curl

Хочу спарсить данные с сайта гибdd https://xn--90adear.xn--p1ai/check/driver. Делаю вот так:

```
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 60);
    $cookieFile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'ccf');
    $timeOut = ini_get('max_execution_time') - 5;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array(
        $ch,
        [
            CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 3,
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => $timeOut,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => $timeOut,
            CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => $cookieFile,
            CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => $cookieFile,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => [
                "num" => "7746468933",
                "date" => "2010-16-20",
                "captchaWord" => "",
                "reCaptchaToken" => "03........FU"
            ],
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://xn--b1afk4ade.xn--90adear.xn--p1ai/proxy/check/driver',
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:81.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0',
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
                'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1',
                'Pragma: no-cache',
                'Cache-Control: no-cache',
                'Origin: https://xn--90adear.xn--p1ai',
                'Referer: https://xn--90adear.xn--p1ai/check/driver',
            ],
        ]
    );
    
    var_dump(curl_exec($ch));

    curl_close($ch);
```

В итоге получаю bool(false) Failed to connect to xn--b1afk4ade.xn--90adear.xn--p1ai port 443: Время ожидания соединения истекло странно, но почему он не коннектит ? с браузера норм.. должен получить ошибку 201 по идее, что капча не прошла. А получаю false. Подскажите пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо.

CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false, - Не помогает.

Comment: см. curl_error https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Comment: Failed to connect to xn--b1afk4ade.xn--90adear.xn--p1ai port 443: Время ожидания соединения истекло странно, но почему он не коннектит ? с браузера норм

Comment: на одной машине делаете и то и другое?

Comment: да, на хостинге (jino.ru). так же пробовал и на 000webhost

Comment: в статье написано что работает только с российских айпи https://www.diggernaut.ru/blog/reshaem-google-recaptcha-v3-servis-rucaptcha-integrirovan-v-platformu-diggernaut/

Comment: спасибо большое за статью! буду разбираться

Answer (score 1):

Причин может быть несколько, но вижу что Вы подключаетесь по https, а в настройках curl не указали версию протокола SSL.
Попробуйте добавить следующие команды :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); //не производить варификацию сертификата
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_DEFAULT);
```

а далее попробуйте отловить вывод:

```
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $errno = curl_errno($ch);
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
```

Comment: более подробно с константами curl по ссылке : https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: без изменений((  вывод пустой..

Comment: скорее всего на 443 порт ругается recaptcha при неответе (https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/releases/6TWYOsKNtRFaLeFqv5xN42-l/recaptcha__ru.js). Посмотрите логи во вкладке "сеть" хрома или ff

Comment: что curl_getinfo($ch) возвращает?

Comment: curl_getinfo($ch) возвращает - Array 
Да вроде должен вывалить ошибку 201, что капча не разгадана, но сам запрос пройти должен. я пробовал использовать anti-captcha, подставляя разгаданную капчу через API, результат был тот же(